# HTTPS www redirects in web.config

Tags: redirect, iis, web

I have the following in my web.config to force https;

```
<rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

But I want to force the www. as well so that all of these would go to the https://www version. What I need to achieve:

```
http://www.domain.tld/whatever
http://(no-www)domain.tld/whatever
https://(no-www)domain.tld/whatever
```

Thank you.

Comment: @cfnerd Hi, I used that first but it doesn't include how to force the www. part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule will do the following:

- Redirect to HTTPS
- Force www

`<rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">

<match url="(.*)" />

<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">

<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />

<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www." negate="true" />

</conditions>

<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />

</rule>`

All that you need is to change `www.example.com` with your domain name